# Pass offset and limit in Drupal embed view

Tags: 7, views

I am having below code to embed a view

```
$view=views_get_view('questions');
$view->set_display('block');

// execute view
$view->execute();
$viewArray = $view->result;
```

How do I set an offset in this? So that I can get the content I need?

I will be displaying a set of content in a page after processing it. I will need to skip first contents sometime. Like skip first 1 sometime or first 3 some other time.

Comment: | How do I set an offset in this? So that I can get the content I need?

What do you mean by offset?  What content are you trying to retrieve? Are you just trying to return the block display of the view?

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope it explains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

| skip first 1 sometime or first 3 some other time.

Is there a reason you can't do this in the view? If you use a pager you can specify an on offset in pager options.

If you need to do this in code, you do something like:

```
$view=views_get_view('questions');
$view->display['block']->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = 'OFFSET NUMBER';
$view->execute_display('block'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in that way:

```
$view = views_get_view('testimonials');
$view->set_display('block');
$view->set_offset($offset);
$view->set_items_per_page(2);
$content = $view->preview();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in a custom module using `hook_view_pre_view()` like so:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function MODULENAME_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'whatever' && $display_id == 'something') {
    $view->set_offset(5);
    $view->set_items_per_page(10);
  }
}
```

- [`hook_views_pre_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7)
- [`set_offset()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aset_offset/7)
- [`set_items_per_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aset_items_per_page/7)